# Insert image using parameter

Tags: sql-server, image, t-sql, parameters

I'm trying to insert an image to a column `Foto` in table `tblWerknemers` using a stored procedure.

Without parameters it's working fine.

But when I use parameters I get the following error:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Procedure procFotoWerknemerToevoegen, Line 10
>   Cannot bulk load. The file "' + @fotonaam + '" does not exist.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procFotoWerknemerToevoegen] 
    @Fotonaam nvarchar(50),
    @WerknemerID int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblWerknemers 
    SET Foto = (SELECT  MyImage.* 
                FROM Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @fotonaam + ''', Single_Blob) MyImage)
    WHERE WerknemerID = @WerknemerID
END
```

Some help would be welcome.

Comment: Try adding one more single quote around @fotonaam. i.e., `... '''' + @fotonaam + ''''...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'UPDATE tblWerknemers 
SET Foto = (SELECT  MyImage.* from Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @fotonaam + ''', Single_Blob) MyImage)
 WHERE WerknemerID = ' + cast(@WerknemerID as nvarchar(50))
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this error:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UPDATE tblWerknemers 
SET Foto = (SELECT  MyImage.* from Openrowset(Bulk 'c:\SQLDatabases\FotosArtemis\Margareta.jpg', Single_Blob) MyImage)
 WHERE WerknemerID = ' to data type int.

Comment: @B.Poels If it solved your problem. Why not accepting the answer??!!

Comment: @B.Poels Or if you solved in another way. Write your answer and accept it. So others this topic can help them